# push element down when another element is added

Tags: php, html, css

So I'm using php to do my form validation on the server side. So when the user submits the form, and if there are any mistakes, I put a message into an array and display them. I would like to display them on top of the form but I need the form to be pushed so there's room for the errors div. This is what I have. I've tried playing around with the margin and padding of the div but that did not do anything. Any help will be appreciated. Note the positioning of all elements on my page is relative.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_ad']))
{
    $required_fields = array("Title" => $_POST['title'], "Author" => $_POST['author'],
         "Price" => $_POST['price'], "Description" => $_POST['description'],
         "Email" => $_POST['email'], "Fixed or Negotiable option" => $_POST['p_cond']);
    foreach ($required_fields as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value == "")
        {
            $errors[] = "$key is required";
        }
    }
    if (!empty($errors))
    {
        $errors_1 = output_errors($errors);
        echo "<div id='errors'> $errors_1</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't describe your problem. How is it not working according to what you want?

Comment: When the div is displayed, it does not move the form in any way, it overlaps the form.